# Sets of integers represented by products of $q(q^n-1)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Consider $X=\{q(q^n-1)|q \ \text{is some power of a prime number}, n\in \Bbb N^*\}$, $S=\{ s \in \Bbb N| s=\prod_i s_i, s_i \in X\} $, I am interested in which integers are in $S$. For example, $2, 6 \in S$ while $5 \notin S$.

1. Does $S$ have a positive density?
2. Does there exist arbitrary long consecutive sequences in $S$?

Comment: Uh, why is 2 in S and 4 not in S?  Gerhard "S Is Not Multiplicatively Closed?" Paseman, 2018.06.12.

Comment: Are you requiring the $s_i$ to be distinct?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it to make it clear that $s_i$ can be the same.

Comment: All members of $X$ are even, so all members of $S$ are even (unless you count $1$ as the empty product), so you can't have even two consecutive integers in $S$ (except $1,2$ if you count $1$ as the empty product).

Answer (score 1):

By my calculations, there are $1254$   members of $S$ up to $10^5$.  Plots seem to indicate $S_n$ growing faster than linearly with $n$, perhaps like $c n^2$ for some constant $c$.  So the asymptotic density appears to be $0$.

Comment: Could you please delete this answer? I found the problem boring so I want to delete it.

Comment: Please don't delete it.  When somebody has taken the time and trouble to answer a question, it's very annoying to have it disappear.

Comment: Fine, I agree with you.